# FirebaseAuth current user is not returning null after calling sign out?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am trying to logout user and switch the widgets but after calling the following function -

```
void logoutUser() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
```

If I check for the current user, it's returning user object but with null id -

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()
```

I try to kick the user out to main.dart after logout which checks if user is signed in or not and loads a correct widget. Does anyone have any idea why `currentUser()` isn't returning null after calling `signOut()`?

Answer (score 0):

`_auth.currentUser()` is probably [returning an anonymous FirebaseUser object](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart#L341). Check the `isAnonymous` property.

Example :

```
auth.currentUser().then((user) {
  if (user == null || user.isAnonymous) {
    // what will you do?
    return;
  }
  setState(() {
    _uid = user.uid;
  });
});
```

Yet, I would highly recommend to [monitor the onAuthStateChanged stream instead](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart#L138). This way you will be informed when the user logs in or logs out immediately.

Check [this article](https://medium.com/@doyinolarewaju/firebase-adding-extra-information-to-user-on-sign-up-and-other-tips-4ebe215866e#60f0), it covers it in depth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Feu but using async is problem. I can't switch widgets based on `then` in my code. If I will do that, it builds both widgets every time I  open the app which I am trying to avoid as they both are heavy.

Comment: Check the article, maybe you can manage it with `Stream Builder`. About your question, was `isAnonymous` the problem?

Comment: It's not the isAnonymous is problem, it's then(user) is. If I do that, in case of user is logged in, I will end up building both the widgets and they will get switched based on user logged in or not. I was trying to avoid that but doesn't seem like there is any cleaner solution at the moment.

Comment: The solution I came up with, is using an IndexedStack and switch between login and main page based on user's current log in state.